How to find the vector that points in the direction of 0 gradient?
I have a multivariate function of 6 variables $F(\vec{x})$ and I want to find a method to determine the direction of $0$ gradient. I have the fact that the derivative along a vector $\vec{u}$ of $F$ can be calculated and set to $0$ as follows:
$$\nabla F\cdot\vec{u}=0$$
I'm not sure where to go from here, though.
I would like to actually understand this rather than just get an answer I can't fathom because I can't think in 6D, so if we decompose it to a 3D surface, i.e. $F(x,y)$ and $\vec{u}=(u_1, u_2)$, I would like to know how I would go about finding the direction of zero gradient of such a surface.

$\nabla F$ is a vector that you can denote by $\vec{v},.$ There can be more than just one $\vec{u}$ that is orthogonal to $\vec{v},.$ Think about this.

Have you thought about this in the more-intuitive situation where there are 3 variables instead of 6?

@MarkS. I have (see the last paragraph of my question), I tried to do it by hand, but couldn't find a general way to do it that could be scaled up to 6D. My main idea is that I want to move around the manifold of $F$ along the curve of 0 gradient, but trying to find that direction to move in at each point is not easy. As Kurt G. said, there's more than one $u$ and I think I'm just getting lost when I find myself with fewer equations than elements of $u$ and thus not being able to numerically evaluate $u$
